# how to fix AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'bit_length'

Tags: python-3.x

i have some error in my code:

```
if type(random) is BuiltinMethod or type(getrandbits) is Method:
                k = n.bit_length()  # don't use (n-1) here because n can be 1
                r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
                while r >= n:
                    r = getrandbits(k)
                return r
```

> AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'bit_length'

Comment: Please show us some more code - where does `n` come from? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: What is `BuiltinMethod` and `Method`? What is `k` and what is `n`? How is `getrandbits` defined! You have to provide your entire source code for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to produce a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) object, e.g.:

```
>>> map(float, range(3))
<map object at 0x10287cf98>
>>> 
>>> list(map(float, range(3)))
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
```

It's pretty clear you expect `n` should be an `int`, e.g.:

```
>>> n = 63
>>> n.bit_length()
6
>>> n += 1
>>> n.bit_length()
7
```

You chose not to show us all relevant code.
But somewhere along the line, your code assigned a `map` object to `n`,
rather than an integer.
That produced the *AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'bit_length'* diagnostic.